# xamarin forms restrict app's supported orientations

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am developing a xamarin forms app and I want to restrict the app's supported orientation to be Portrait only. I have indicated so in the info.plist file. But, the app still rotates when I rotate the device / simulator. What am I missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Xamarin Studio in that the GUI checkboxes only affect orientation for iPhone, not iPad. I will get a bug report filed, but in the meantime just view the Source for the Info.plist (Click the `Source` tab at the bottom of the Info.plist document  and look for `Supported interface orientations (iPad)` which contains an array of values. Delete all of the values except `Portrait (bottom button)` from the array for `Supported interface orientations (iPad)`

UPDATE: Bug filed: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=50552